# visual studio exp2010 Win32 release build has different integer size when compiled on 64 bit machine

Tags: visual-c++-2010

When I compile my project on Win7 64 bit platform in Debug mode I get the expected 32 bit integers. Something happens when compiling in Release mode where the integers become 64 bit. It mainly affects a bitmap header struct that I am using. Does anyone know how to force VS to compile for 32 bit?.

Comment: You are describing "magical" and unrealistic behavior. The problem is in something else. The OS has nothing to do with it. The project configuration might. Anyway. what "integers" are you talking about? What specific types?

Comment: No, integers don't just randomly change their size. If you're getting 64 bit where you expected 32, you're not compiling for the same target.

Comment: I have Win32 selected for both builds. When I debug the release code hovering the mouse over a variable it definitely shows it's 64 bit and obviously the struct doesn't match up. I don't understand why but it is definitely happening.

Comment: The integer size is not changing randomly. It is consistent between debug and release builds.

Comment: I ran another few tests in debug and release mode, when I step through in debug mode my variable unsigned int BMPWidth is 0x0023 (correct 4 bytes). In release mode some lines are skipped but this variable now shows 0x00230000 (8 Bytes). In this mode the debugger also doesn't allow access to every line, i.e I cant put break points on some of them yet others work fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @PeterS: Er... `0x0023` is 2 bytes, while `0x00230000` is 4 bytes. However, you are most likely dealing with some quirk of the debugger itself and the way it acts on optimized code. The variable has the same size in both cases.

Comment: You are right I saw that error 2 min after posting. I was confused by one of the variables in my struct is a short and I was stupidly counting the digits. Maybe it's an alignment problem causing the shift. I already tried disabling all optimizations. What I don't understand is why the code compiles and runs in debug build but compiles but won't run in release build.

Answer (score 0):

OK Solved my misunderstanding of the problem. The Struct Member Alignment was set to default which caused the initial fault with Release build. What threw me was trying to debug the Release build to find out what was going wrong. I found a thread that mentioned the fact that Release build may not follow the source code and some lines may be missing. Once setting the member alignment to byte the exe file ran without an issue even though the debug still showed missing lines and could not locate symbols. Thanks for every ones patience and input it was a great help in finding a solution for my first question post.